# Trouble in using MT3329 SKM53 GPS module

Tags: arduino, avr, serial, atmega, gps

I bought a SKM53 GPS module a few months ago. I tried hard to make it work but couldn't get anything out of it. I was thinking it's a fault with the device *(actually i thought i burned it by not properly giving the supply)*. So I didn't think much and ordered another one ([here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/260980774751?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649)).

I received the second module (same, SKM53) today. Well.. something is not right, it behaves exactly as the previous one! I'm not familiar with the module, but thought that was something easy to use. I tested with the example sketch "simple_test" that comes with the arduino core library, *TinyGPS* (see below). When observing the serial monitor, all values are zero. Also, the seemingly LED *(i assumed)*, next to '1206' (see image), is not lighting..

[image]

Does all that mean the module is not working? Hoping not, what can I do to make it work?(I tested on a open ground where the sky is clearly visible.)

**Sketch (simple_test)**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <TinyGPS.h>

/* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 10(rx) and 11(tx).
*/

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(10, 11);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(4800);

  Serial.print("Simple TinyGPS library v. "); 
  Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
  Serial.println();
}

void loop()
{
  bool newData = false;
  unsigned long chars;
  unsigned short sentences, failed;

  // For one second we parse GPS data and report some key values
  for (unsigned long start = millis(); millis() - start < 1000;)
  {
    while (ss.available())
    {
      char c = ss.read();
      // Serial.write(c); // uncomment this line if you want to see the GPS data flowing
      if (gps.encode(c)) // Did a new valid sentence come in?
        newData = true;
    }
  }

  if (newData)
  {
    float flat, flon;
    unsigned long age;
    gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
    Serial.print("LAT=");
    Serial.print(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : flat, 6);
    Serial.print(" LON=");
    Serial.print(flon == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : flon, 6);
    Serial.print(" SAT=");
    Serial.print(gps.satellites() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES ? 0 : gps.satellites());
    Serial.print(" PREC=");
    Serial.print(gps.hdop() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP ? 0 : gps.hdop());
  }

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  Serial.print(" CHARS=");
  Serial.print(chars);
  Serial.print(" SENTENCES=");
  Serial.print(sentences);
  Serial.print(" CSUM ERR=");
  Serial.println(failed);
}
```

**Observed output**

```
Simple TinyGPS library v. 12
by Mikal Hart

 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
 CHARS=0 SENTENCES=0 CSUM ERR=0
```

---

**EDIT**

This is the working code I used, by editing an example that comes with `TinyGPS` lib. Uses hardware serial, USART1, instead of software serial.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <TinyGPS.h>

/* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
 It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
 4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 3(rx) and 4(tx).
 */

TinyGPS gps;

static void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps);
static bool feedgps();
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);
static void print_str(const char *str, int len);

void setup()
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);     //GPS module is connected to USART1
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("Testing TinyGPS library v. "); 
  Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Sizeof(gpsobject) = "); 
  Serial.println(sizeof(TinyGPS));
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Sats HDOP Latitude Longitude Fix  Date       Time       Date Alt     Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum");
  Serial.println("          (deg)    (deg)     Age                        Age  (m)     --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail");
  Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}

void loop()
{
  bool newdata = false;
  unsigned long start = millis();

  // Every second we print an update
  while (millis() - start < 1000)
  {
    if (feedgps())
      newdata = true;
  }
  gpsdump(gps);
}

static void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  float flat, flon;
  unsigned long age, date, time, chars = 0;
  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
  static const float LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

  print_int(gps.satellites(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES, 5);
  print_int(gps.hdop(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP, 5);
  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
  print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 9, 5);
  print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 5);
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);

  print_date(gps);

  print_float(gps.f_altitude(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ALTITUDE, 8, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_course(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_speed_kmph(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_SPEED, 6, 2);
  print_str(gps.f_course() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(gps.f_course()), 6);
  print_int(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0UL : (unsigned long)TinyGPS::distance_between(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON) / 1000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  print_float(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0.0 : TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, 51.508131, -0.128002), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_str(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON)), 6);

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  print_int(chars, 0xFFFFFFFF, 6);
  print_int(sentences, 0xFFFFFFFF, 10);
  print_int(failed, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  Serial.println();
}

static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
  else
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
  Serial.print(sz);
  feedgps();
}

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
    sz[len] = 0;
    if (len > 0) 
      sz[len-1] = ' ';
    for (int i=7; i<len; ++i)
      sz[i] = ' ';
    Serial.print(sz);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1);
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
      Serial.print(" ");
  }
  feedgps();
}

static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  int year;
  byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
  unsigned long age;
  gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
  if (age == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE)
    Serial.print("*******    *******    ");
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d   ",month, day, year, hour, minute, second);
    Serial.print(sz);
  }
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
  feedgps();
}

static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  feedgps();
}

static bool feedgps()
{
  while(Serial1.available()>0)
  {
    char c= Serial1.read();
    if (gps.encode(c))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a picture of your setup?

Comment: What Arduino type do you use? http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial Look at limitations.

Comment: When you power it up, do you see periodic messages on the TX line? Many GPS devices are configured to automatically send out messages once powered on.

Comment: Look at TXD and RXD with a voltmeter, are they usually High at 5V?

Comment: @jippie the setup is pretty simple. I did as the example sketch suggests. VCC to 5v, GND to ground, NC and RC left unconnected, (_whoa!_)Rx to 3 and Tx to 4. I'm using Arduino Mega, so (i checked the limitations) changed Rx to 10 and Tx 11 (and changed the sketch accordingly). Anything wrong?

Comment: @kenny how can I test it (directly monitoring GPS output) ?

Comment: It should be sending NMEA on TX line. Perhaps you switched between the two? They are usually cross connected (TX to RX of uC and RX to TX of uC)

Comment: Update the sketch in your question accordingly, as @GustavoLitovsky suggests, check TX/RX order. A picture can still be helpful.

Comment: @Anubis a scope is the best way, but you may be able to get by with a DMM as Gustavo suggests. The input/RX should be floating and the output/TX mostly high with a pulse of data every so often.

Comment: @kenny i think i'm going to love you!! i just tried connecting GPS Tx to my wireless transmitters Rx. Man! I started to receive this weird, but seemingly sensible output,

'$GPRMC,171128.529,V,,,,,0.93,132.98,050113,,,N*4a=
$GPGGA,171130.000,,,,,0,2,,,M,,M,,*4F
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E' (_etc..._)

can I be happy? the module is at least working? then probably jippie's guess was correct. The fault may be with the setup. waiting till he come back..
(and kenny above comment is still valid. What is the **proper** way of testing it?)

Comment: sorry guys didn't see the new comments. what should i do now ?

Comment: @Anubis those look like NMEA sentences. You'll probably only need the GPRMC ones. Good luck.

Comment: @kenny wait! so why can't Arduino receive the GPS Tx? (this is GPS direct output). I need to process GPS data in uC..

Comment: @Anubis I don't understand your question. Connect the GPS TX to the uC's RX at the same baud/settings, and you should get those GPS/NMEA sentences.

Comment: @Anubis
can u post the new code with hardware serial config????????
please and thank you

Comment: @memo20080858 see the edited post, I've included the code i used. It's pretty simple, you just have to configure and use some hardware serial module instead of the used software serial object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'd better update the IDE to a [latest version](http://arduino.cc/en/main/software) (if you haven't already done). There are some bugs in previous IDEs.

As you are using Arduino mega, you have to check the `SoftwareSerial` [library docs](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) and figure out what pins can be used in Mega. As mentioned in one of the comments, there are some limitations in the lib.  *(you won't be able to directly use the examples that comes with the IDE as they use D2, D3 pins which are not supported in Mega)*

However, there are many USART modules in Mega. Why not use hardware serial instead of using virtual ones?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with that module. [This](http://www.fut-electronics.com/wp-content/plugins/fe_downloads/Uploads/Connecting%20Skylab%20SKM53%20GPS%20module%20with%20Arduino%20and%20Demo%20code.pdf) can be useful.

Comment: I've followed that before. However I've figured out the issue. The problem was with the `SoftwareSerial` library, as some people suggested above, it doesn't support some of the pins of Arduino Mega. After changing the `Tx` pin to 10, it worked. Thanks for the support anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use baudrate 9600. I made it work, but with some limitations. It drops randomly some parts of the sentences (maybe because of the SoftwareSerial/NewSoftwareSerial I'm using. Increasing the buffer size of SoftwareSerial doesn't seem to help).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is already solved. The issue was that i wasn't using correct pins with Arduino Mega. The module is working perfectly now. However, as Arduino mega got several hardware serial modules, i'm using one of them with the module. I guess what you are using software serial with some heavy code. If you don't read the module fast enough, you may loose some of the incoming bytes..

Answer (score 0):

I found this post very helpful, may be you too.
http://hotresistor.blogspot.com/2014/11/arduino-interfacing-with-gps-tutorial.html

Comment: Can you edit a few more details from that link into your answer? Link-only answers are discouraged because they can become useless in the future if the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

Try powering the GPS with external voltage regulator using the configuration from the following link http://competefornothing.com/l7805-voltage-regulator-for-arduino-5v-1amp/

Comment: Can you edit a few more details from that link into your answer? Link-only answers are discouraged because they can become useless in the future if the link dies.